# Change background colour of a ComboBox in WPF without pasting entire template?

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I understand you can right click, Edit Template > Edit a Copy, paste the entire ComboBox template then change a few lines, but is there really not a way to change the background in just a few lines of code?

I was able to achieve it with this code, but that eliminates the dropdown arrow/menu which basically makes it useless.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: This is one instance that is so frustrating about WPF. 80 lines to be able to adjust a background. From my experience with the ComboBox, you have to create a whole template for the entire thing. Although one thought I have that may be possible is if you add a style for the inner object types and target them. For Example, within the ComboBox, add a general style for TextBlock and change that background, Then add one for ToggleButton. Not sure if it will work, but only way I can think of without redoing the whole template.

Comment: Oh okay, I'll play around with that and see what happens, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid you cannot "override" only a part of a `ControlTemplate` and given the way the default `ControlTemplate` of the `ComboBox` is defined, you cannot simply set or property or create a derived style with a trigger to change the background colour of it. This is explained in detail [here](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/04/30/changing-the-background-colour-of-a-combobox-in-wpf-on-windows-8/).

What you can do is to change the background of the loaded template element at runtime programmtically:

```
private void ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
    ToggleButton toggleButton = comboBox.Template.FindName("toggleButton", comboBox) as ToggleButton;
    if (toggleButton != null)
    {
        Border border = toggleButton.Template.FindName("templateRoot", toggleButton) as Border;
        if (border != null)
            border.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded">
    <ComboBoxItem Background="Yellow">1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Background="Yellow">2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Background="Yellow">3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

The other option is to copy the entire template into your XAML markup and edit it as per your requirements.